# PostgreSQL: Allow Linux user to login as given role without password

Tags: postgresql

How to allow `foo` user **only** to login with `psql` or **execute SQL queries** locally as **given role** and **without password**?

```
psql -U my_role
psql -U my_role -d my_database -c "TRUNCATE my_schema.my_table RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `pg_hba.conf` line like this at the beginning:

```
local  all  my_role  trust
```

That will allow passwordless local connections of `my_role` to all databases.